# Best Practices for Storing entity pointers (foreign keys) in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage

Azure Table Storage lets you look up an entity using Table Name, Partition Key, and Row Key.

But if I'm storing a pointer to one entity in another entity (i.e. a foreign key in rdb terms), is the best way to do that to concatenate those 3 values, or is there a more direct way of saying "this other entity exists *here*"? Like a URI that permanently points to the entity's location?

I'm 90% sure the answer IS no but 100% wishing it WERE yes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the URL if you wanted to, but it's not very different from concatenating the table name, partition key, and row key. (The URL also includes the account name, but otherwise it's just a simple formatting of those three pieces of information.)

Comment: Thanks Smarx! Just needed some final clarity.

Comment: BTW - I have another question open that I'm struggling with - would you mind checking it out? I know you're one of the resident Azure experts here :) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597294/how-to-add-new-properties-to-an-entity-saved-in-azure-table-storage