# Adding property to entity in Azure Table Storage seems to add null property to all entities in table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to dynamically add properties to Azure Table Storage using the ReadingEntity and WritingEntity events, as described here: [How to add new properties to an entity saved in Azure Table Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597294/how-to-add-new-properties-to-an-entity-saved-in-azure-table-storage).

The purpose is to save a List property on my poco into table storage. To accomplish this, every time I need to add a new item to the list for an entity, I'm getting that entity out of Table Storage, counting the number of properties with a certain name that the entity has, and then adding another one with the same name and an incremented index at the end - for example, if an entity has properties Friend1, Friend2, and Friend3, I will add Friend4.

The problem I'm hitting is that when I add a property to 1 entity, it seems to add it to all entities in the table (or maybe the partition - I haven't checked). So if I add Friend1 to Entity1, and then add a Friend property to Entity2, I'm expecting to add Entity2.Friend1. Instead, Friend1 seems to already exist on Entity2, with a NULL value. So the code that adds the property sees Friend1 already there, and adds a Friend2 property to Entity2. As if this were a relational database and I'm creating a column in the schema. Obviously this totally destroys my plans for how to store this info ...

Is this how it's supposed to work?? I was working with the understanding that properties could be unique to each entity.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this by any chance against storage emulator (development storage)?

Comment: I'd bet money @GauravMantri's guess is right. :-) Dev storage does weird things... it actually uses a relational database under the hood. Try this with the actual storage service.

Comment: You're right - it is a dev storage emulator that's doing this. Thanks for your help - I'll try to use a real storage account and see what if the problem goes away!

Comment: I got my app up and running in Azure, and the problem went away! Thanks guys. If you want to actually create an answer to this question, I'll accept it so you can get credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaurav and smarx were right - the problem goes away when using the Table Storage Service and not the local storage service emulator.