# October Azure SDK broken when inserting a string with a trailing space

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Has anyone worked out a fix for this problem. When using the storage emulator and inserting a row into table storage then the row insert fails if there is a space at end of the field.

This was pointed out two weeks ago but I still see no updates from Microsoft on this? Does anyone know of a fix ?

[Microsoft forum link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/94ae4da7-8989-46a7-a258-004e6410c6b0)

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104874/table-storage-emulator-insert-fails-with-one-of-the-request-inputs-is-not-val)

Please don't close this question. Having something out here on Stackoverflow might help save someone from the two days I spent trying to work out what was wrong.

Comment: if you are in a hurry you can [fix it yourself](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net), but I would rather work with real storage meantime.

Comment: @astaykov, you linked to the client library source code, but this issue is with the storage emulator, right?

Comment: @smarx, you are right, but one could implement trim() either in client code, or in the client lib. Or just use the real storage meanwhile. Fact is that this issue needs a fix, and that this fix is not going to happen in the next hours.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in later versions of the Windows Azure SDK. Install the latest version to fix the problem.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/