# Windows Azure DataServiceRequestException on certain strings?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I recently "migrated" my azure application to Windows8. I'm getting some weird DataServiceRequestException when adding an object with AddObject() and calling SaveChanges() (immediately after or later in the code). From what I could tell it's related to the object having a string that ends in space. 
Having fiddled around with Fiddler I found that the XML sent to the storage looks like this:

```
...
 <d:Remarks xmlns:space="preserve">Karangetang </d:Remarks>
...
```

I also then tried using UpdateObject() to just change to object to a sub-string of the actual string I wanted. Only those strings that ended in space trowed an exception, even if the string contained double spaces elsewhere.

**Note** that this error happens only in the emulator and doesn't happen on the deployed app (although I haven't redeployed it after going to VS12).

So, why is this happening ?

Comment: I noticed that you have a trailing white space. I believe it's a known issue with storage emulator. Please check this thread on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310296/october-azure-sdk-broken-when-inserting-a-string-with-a-trailing-space. HTH.